# Hide products that aren't selected in the Cognito confirmation email

Tags: cognito-forms

In one form I have about 20 products. When I fill it out and only order **2 items**, I receive a notification email and confirmation email that shows **all** the items (even the ones I did not order).

Is there a way to hide the items in the confirmation and notification email that aren't ordered from a form?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to deselect the "Blank fields" check box.  When setting up your confirmation/notification emails, there is a checkbox for including entries.  When you check it, another option for blank entries appears.  Make sure the blank entries box is unchecked.

[image]